# Connecting FirebaseAuth Emulator to Kotlin Android Project

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I can't seem to get the FirebaseAuth Emulator connecting properly. I am also using Firestore, for which the emulator runs perfectly. Here is my code for initialising the emulators:

```
private lateinit var firestore : FirebaseFirestore
private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth


override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    firebaseAuth.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099)

    firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    firestore.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080)
    firestore.firestoreSettings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder().build()
```

Everything works as expected when using the live version on FirebaseAuth, by commenting out:

```
firebaseAuth.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099)
```

Accessing localhost:9099 in my browser also works fine, so the issue is not with FirebaseAuth itself.

The documentation below only covers Java, so I can't work out what I'm missing.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_auth

Answer (score 1):

Tip:

In file firebase.json (i use VSCode) need set "host" for firestore.

Example:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080,
      "host": "0.0.0.0" // <=== edit here
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```